# WSL - How to roll forward after rolling back to the previous WSL kernel?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-insider, ubuntu-20.04

The latest WSL kernel caused some problems on a package and I reverted it to the previous WSL kernel with `wsl --rollback`.

Now the package update indicates that this issue is resolved. I would like to get back to the latest kernel version. When I type `wsl --status`, it tells me that I am on rollback kernel version. I tried `wsl --update` but it says I am already on the latest kernel. There is nothing showing when I check the Windows updates. I tried to download the [WSL2 kernel update installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel), it told me that I have a newer version installed.

How do I revert this rollback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is no command to revert a rollback by design. However, this is possible at the time being via registry.

- Removed RollbackKernel key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`
- `wsl --shutdown`
- `wsl`

[Please refer to the GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5452#issuecomment-647067945)